# How to represent "all"/"all options"/"show all" as an icon

Tags: icon, symbolism

This to go in a tab. The other tabs show quite separate groups the user might find interesting. This tabs contains all of them.

I've thought about writing "ALL" (capitals seemed more recognisable in this case), but there are icons for all other things, and it makes it harder to translate the application.

Another thought was three checked checkboxes on top of each other, but that seems more like a form to fill in.

Comment: How are your other icons represented?

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - Not entirely sure what you mean there. They are the conventional/most used icons for their respective groups, if that's what you meant. Also in their own tabs.

Comment: I meant, what do your other icons look like :)

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - Still confused here. Do you mean their style? The plan is to use the most universal depictions/icons/representation of what they stand for. A star for favourites for instance.

Comment: Aha, got ya. I think I was confused. I'll write an answer and hope it helps :D

Comment: I see. Suggestions on how to improve the question?

Comment: you can use a closed book as icon and opened  when clicked,its kind of show all

Answer (score 2):

If it is for tabs, I would use icon symbolizing cluster of all things, either something more relaxed [image] or less relaxed [image], depending on overall app style.

Also the target audience is important for the decision, because some audiences may already have their 'all' symbol. For example for advanced computer users, 'all' can be expresed by asterisk (wildcard *).

Answer (score 1):

After the quick discussion, I have used before a simple icon of an eye. It's simple but sometimes can be a bit cartoony. Other ways I experimented with is to have the other icons overlaid on each other in your one icon, so it shows "all tabs."  You ocould also have some sort of columned icon, like a 3 row/column table, but might not be as effective.

Hope some of that helps :)

Comment: I don't think the eye will work, but a collage/combination of multiple other ones, either on top of each other or spread out in, say, a triangle, that might work! :)

Comment: Yeah, the eye worked for a videogame website I made but it was a very specific genre. Collages say a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Opened penknife or pocket tool gear. 
Of course for better legibility you should simplify it.
However it might be too much detailed for something 
you want to place into a tab.

[image]

Comment: I've seen this symbol several times in meaning of 'toolset' (small useful tools to support main purpose).

Comment: Yup. I agree with you. Penknife is better for toolset.